# reading json with object

Tags: php, json

I decoded an incoming string via POST in two JSON and I'm trying to read it and save the keys in vars. these are the arrays:

```
$infos = $_POST;

$orderInformation['orderInfo'] = json_decode($infos['orderinf']);

$orderItensInformation['orderItensInfo'] = json_decode($infos['orderitensinf']);
```

This is what var_dump returns of `$orderInformation`:

```
array(1) {
  ["orderInfo"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (9) {
      ["customer_fone"]=>
      string(10) "5554120082"
      ["neighborhood"]=>
      string(4) "aaaa"
      ["order_price"]=>
      int(45)
      ["payment_method"]=>
      string(8) "CASH"
      ["customer_email"]=>
      string(19) "abc@def.com"
      ["street"]=>
      string(14) "Unknown street"
      ["number"]=>
      string(3) "111"
      ["order_date"]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
        ["day"]=>
        int(3)
        ["month"]=>
        int(11)
        ["time"]=>
        int(1)
        ["year"]=>
        int(2013)
        ["minute"]=>
        int(24)
      }
      ["customer_name"]=>
      string(6) "Noname"
    }
}
```

The question is how do I get the information inside the object?
I tried to use foreach:

```
foreach($orderInformation->orderInfo as $oi) {
      $fone = $oi->customer_fone;
      $nbh = $oi->neighborhood;
       .
       .
       .
}
```

But didn't work. The vars were empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop, unless you have multiple orders in this array

`$orderInformation['orderInfo']` is your object

```
echo $orderInformation['orderInfo']->customer_fone;
// Should return 5554120082
```

For a neater approach, try

```
$x = $orderInformation['orderInfo'];
echo $x->customer_fone;
```

The big err in your code.

`$orderInformation->ordeInfo` does not exist as a property like you are calling it.

`$orderInformation['orderInfo']`

Comment: I agree, in this case foreach is not needed. But should't it works anyways? I'll need foreach to iterate in $orderItensInformation.

Comment: The code you gave would not work because of syntax errors `foreach($orderInformation->orderInfo` AND because `$orderInformation['orderInfo']` is not an array, you cannot loop an object.

The correct code would be `foreach($orderInformation as $order...` and then $order will be your object

Comment: Got it... Is there a way to convert object to array? Where customer_fone, neighborhood,... would be associative keys in this array. thx!

Comment: You sure can! Just add another argument to your json_decode call with a value of true.
`json_decode($infos['orderinf'], true)`

Comment: I'll try it later, with $orderItensInformation! foreach($orderInformation as $order... works well btw. Thanks for your help, it was really helpful! ;)

Answer (score 0):

[From the manual](https://www.php.net/json_decode), return will be an object unless your second parameter passed into it is set to true, which will return an associative array (might be more suitable for you in this case):

```
$orderInformation['orderInfo'] = json_decode($infos['orderinf'], true);

$orderItensInformation['orderItensInfo'] = json_decode($infos['orderitensinf'], true);

foreach($orderInformation['orderInfo'] as $oi) {
      $fone = $oi['customer_fone'];
      $nbh = $oi['neighborhood'];
       .
       .
       .
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that its possible to convert object to array parsing true argument. I'll read the manual, thank you! ;)

Comment: No problem, but you should read the manual before you ask here next time.